# what is the difference between while and do-while loop in c?

Tags: c++, c

I am new to programming language. Anyone please help me with this. It helps to improve my skills.

what is the difference between while and do-while loop in c

Thank You,

Comment: Please tag one language, even though this is the same in both c and c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while loop:

A while loop is a control flow statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a given Boolean condition. The while loop can be thought of as a repeating if statement.

do-while loop:

do while loop is similar to while loop with the only difference that it checks for the condition after executing the statements, and therefore is an example of Exit Control Loop.

[for more info click here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-while-and-do-while-loop-in-c-c-java/)